# How to create non-public shared nodejs module with typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I have a concept of a nodejs server service, that consists of

1. a rest API and
2. some asynchronous workers.

Both should live in different subnets and git repositories. But both access database and should use the same entities and types.

So I would like to have something like shared module (don't know the proper term in npm ecosystem) with just entities / types, that would use typescript and use that shared module in both rest API and async workers. The shared module needs to be versioned in git separate (private) repository.

How can I do this in nodejs? 
So far I read something about treating it like a library ([here](https://www.tsmean.com/articles/how-to-write-a-typescript-library/local-consumer/) and [here](https://www.tsmean.com/articles/how-to-write-a-typescript-library/)). I especially don't know, how and where should I put the js files, compiled from typescript.

Comment: It sounds like you want to publish to private npm scope?

Comment: I may not use proper terms. I just need to version the rest api, the shared entities and the async workers in three independent git repositories, which will be located on company's private Git server.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is versioning, maybe consider treating it like a regular npm module?

[npm-install](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) supports git repositories  and git supports release tags [release tags](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging)

From those two all you need to do is compile typescript to an index.js file at the root of the module (library), and you can access it by require inside where it's needed.

(just be mindful that you will need each shared repository to have a package.json)